# useSelector into function throws error hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, hook

I'm trying to understand what the difference between use in useSelector into the _bootstrapAsync that it's failed in this way

```
    import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function authLoading({ navigation }) {

  const _bootstrapAsync = () => {
    const authData = useSelector(state=>state.Auth);

    console.log('authData',authData)
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    _bootstrapAsync()

  },[]);


  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      <Text>Auth Loading</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

it throws the error

> hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

but when i can useSelector outside it works fine..

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function authLoading({ navigation }) {
  const authData = useSelector(state=>state.Auth);

  const _bootstrapAsync = () => {
    console.log('authData',authData)
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    _bootstrapAsync()

  },[]);


  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      <Text>Auth Loading</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Hook is for only functional components to reduce the complexity of complex class components. Now you can split the complex class component in small functional components and follow the life cycle as a class component using Hooks.

You can only use Hooks within the functional component or body as shown in error. And you can also customize Hook creating your hook.

[Here you can see how to use hook within useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)